# 50s Sci Fi book: "Superbomb" sends town to far future with Sun a red giant star

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I once read a book about 40 years ago that was from the early 1950s.

The premise was a scientist working on a "Superbomb" (described as a Hydrogen bomb) in a rural American town/city. An atomic war breaks out and the city is hit.

The bomb doesn't destroy the town; instead the town is catapulted millions of years into the future where the Sun is a growing red giant star and humanity is long gone.

Aliens find the town and help the folk out somehow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[*The City at World's End](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20170)*** by **Edmond Hamilton.** First published in the magazine [***Startling Stories* (July 1950**)](https://archive.org/stream/Startling_Stories_v21n03_1950-07#page/n11/mode/2up), and then printed as a book in 1951, and reprinted on various occasions since. In fact, I just now discovered that you could get an e-book version of it for Kindle, [via Amazon's website](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FKFKVVS), as part of a package deal which includes 15 other stories by the same author, conveniently collected in one big "Megapack," all for a mere 55 cents (U.S. money).

I own one of the paperback reprints, with the cover art shown below (which may ring a bell for you?), but I don't have my copy on hand to let me quote passages from it, so I'm going to settle for quoting some material from a lengthy review on Goodreads to demonstrate that you are thinking of the same story I read some years ago.

[image: Cover of "City at World's End" by Edmond Hamilton, showing a black sky, a red landscape with a glass-domed city and a line of people visible in the background, and two human silhouettes in the foreground]

You said:

> The premise was a scientist working on a "Superbomb" (described as a
> Hydrogen bomb) in a rural American town/city. An atomic war breaks out
> and the city is hit.
>
> The bomb doesn't destroy the town; instead the town is catapulted
> millions of years into the future where the Sun is a growing red giant
> star and humanity is long gone.

The review posted by a guy called "Sandy" on the book's [Goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/641633.City_at_World_s_End) says, in part:

> The novel strains the reader's credulity in its opening pages, but if
> you can get past them alright, and buy into the central premise,
> you'll be home free. In "City at World's End," the reader is
> introduced to the small city of Middletown, in Anywhere, U.S.A.; a
> burg of some 50,000 souls going about their business on a beautiful
> June morning. What the citizens of Middletown don't know, however, is
> that its local industrial laboratory is actually the secret working
> site of a group of atomic physicists, which makes the otherwise
> undistinguished locale a prime target in a potential war. And before
> the citizenry is even aware of it, a so-called "super atomic" is
> exploded right over their heads, knocking one and all off their feet.
> And that's all! As the populace dusts itself off, it is noticed that
> the air is now very much colder, and that the sun has changed to a
> gloomy-looking red ball in the heavens. The moon is now enormous, the
> stars are visible in the daytime sky, and the lab scientists, by
> analyzing those changed star patterns, soon come to realize the
> impossible truth: The city of Middletown has somehow been blown, via a
> rift in the time-space continuum, millions of years into Earth's
> future!

You said:

> Aliens find the town and help the folk out somehow.

Sandy on Goodreads says:

> In the book's next section, men from outer space, representing the
> League of Stars, arrive near New Middletown in response to its radioed
> pleas for assistance; these Earthmen of the future and their alien
> shipmates help get New Middletown going but then insist on evacuating
> the 20th century community to another, more livable world, much
> against the wishes of the old-fashioned folk. Thus, in "City at
> World's End"'s next section, it is up to Kenniston, as the city's
> representative, to go to the galaxy's capital world near Vega and
> plead his neighbors' case before the Board of Governors. And before he
> knows it, he has also become embroiled in a plot involving the
> futuristic scientist Jon Arnol, who claims to have invented an "energy
> bomb" that can revive a dying planet....

Put these points of similarity together with your recollection that the story dated back to the early 1950s, and I don't think there's any room for doubt!

Comment: @user14111 Thank you for the offer, but I don't think I need to add quotes at this point. I feel uncomfortable with swiping chunks of text from your old Answer just to beef up mine a bit. I need to work on fixing a psychological blind spot -- last night it *never occurred* to me to search the site for previous Answers about the same book. For some reason, that only tends to occur to me with Story-ID Questions that I recognize as asking about fairly recent books (within the last 30 years, say), or such popular classics as Herbert's *Dune* or Heinlein's *The Moon Is a Harsh Mistress.*

Answer (score 8):

That sounds like "City at World's End" by Edmond Hamilton, 1951.  The town had something to do with advanced weapons development, which was why they believe they were targeted by a first strike.  A quote to check: "That furry brute is a technician?"  They eventually revive the Earth by heating up the core of the planet.

Comment: Oops! Looks like stolenmoment posted his Answer while I was tracking down and pasting in a copy of the cover art that I remember from my own copy, and so forth. Beat me by a few minutes!

Comment: That's it!!Thank you, guys ... especially for the Kindle tip!

Comment: @user14111 I said I wouldn't swipe paragraphs from your old Answer, but I *did* decide to incorporate your link to the original magazine version into my answer. I did it for the benefit of anyone who stumbles across this Question at some later date and doesn't want to spend 55 cents to read the story on a Kindle.